# Multithreading c++ breaks the code raising an unknown exception

Tags: c++, multithreading

I am trying to explore multithreading in c++. Let me give you my code

```
Class Sender{
run();
start(){
         start a thread with run std::thread pSt(&Sender::run, this);
        pSt.join()
       }
}

Class SendRunThread{
    void run(Sender sndr_)
    {
        sndr_.start();
    }
}
```

Now 
I am having the following lines of code in the main method

```
Sender sndr1();
SendRunThread *s = new SendRunThread(); 
std::thread t1(&SendRunThread::run, s,sndr1);       
t1.join();
delete s;

Sender sndr2();
SendRunThread *s1 = new SendRunThread();
std::thread t2(&SendRunThread::run, s1, sndr2);     
t2.join();
delete s1;
```

If I have one sndr object, the thread works perfectly fine. If I try it with 2 sndr objects it breaks. I would be glad if some one explains me the reason.

Comment: what do you think this line will do `Sender sndr1();`?

Comment: @billz It creates a new instance of Sender class.

Comment: You seem to be trying to declare functions without return type; don't.

Comment: Also, you're trying to pass pointers to a function that takes values. There's a lot wrong here.

Comment: @CoffeeandCode Hey. I havent pasted the full code. Its just a high level gist of the code which I have.

Comment: Well, we can't find the issue you're having if the whole thing is full of issues. Post proper code, otherwise how is somebody supposed to diagnose?

Comment: @CoffeeandCode Hey. I cant paste the full code in the question. You can view the code in this link http://pastebin.com/jjhAuFEY

Comment: Could you specify "It breaks" more clearly? Copy the compiler/linker/runtime error to here. Also what billz means with the first comment is that you declared a function called    sndr1    that returns a    Sender    and takes no arguments. Get rid of the    ()    .